# event.target.type === 'select' is not working in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple fields in my form like:-

- input type text
- input type radio
- input type checkbox
- select

here is all value working fine but `select` not working.

My Code:

```js
handleChange = event => {
        if (event.target.type === 'text' || event.target.type === 'radio' || event.target.type === 'select') {
            this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        } else {
            this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
        }
    };
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: We can't help you without more information. But what debugging have you done? For instance, what do you see when you put a breakpoint on that line and look at `event.target.type`? Remember that `event.target` can be a **descendant** element of the element you hooked the event on (which is `event.currentTarget`).

Comment: did you try to log the types before the if check ?

Comment: You have `<input type="text" />`, `<input type="radio" />`, `<input type="checkbox" />` and... `<select>`. And you're surprised that `<select>` doesn't have a `type`? You should use `event.target.nodeName === 'SELECT'` or `event.target instanceof HTMLSelectElement`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol  thank you so much "event.target.nodeName === 'SELECT'" it is working fine for me thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `switch` statement and check the `tagName` and `type` of the form elements to determine how to grab the value.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const StatefulForm = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  const handleFormDataChange = (key, newValue) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [key]: newValue });
  };

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { checked, name, tagName, type, value } = target;
    const form = target.closest('form');
    const field = form.elements[name];

    switch (tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'input':
        switch (type) {
          case 'checkbox':
            handleFormDataChange(name, {
              checked: [...field].some(c => c.checked),
              value: [...field].filter(c => c.checked).map(c => c.value)
            });
            break;
          case 'radio':
            handleFormDataChange(name, { checked, value });
            break;
          default:
            handleFormDataChange(name, value);
            break; 
        }
        break;
      case 'select':
        handleFormDataChange(name, target.hasAttribute('multiple')
          ? [...field.selectedOptions].map(s => s.value) : value);
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <form class="StatefulForm" onChange={handleChange}>
      <div className="FormChildren">
        {children}
      </div>
      <div className="JsonState">{JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)}</div>
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <StatefulForm>
    <input name="text" type="text" />
    <select name="select" multiple>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
      <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input name="radio" type="radio" value="1" />
      <input name="radio" type="radio" value="2" />
      <input name="radio" type="radio" value="3" />
    </div>
  </StatefulForm>
);

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.StatefulForm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0.5em;
}

.FormChildren {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.33em;
}

.JsonState {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```